# Операции сравнения полиномов произвольной степени

Tags: c++, массивы, ооп, сравнение, полином

Помогите правильно сформулировать операции сравнения, т.к. все мои попытки не увенчались успехом. Получается, что: полиномы у нас равны, если равны их степени, а потом и каждый коэффициент. Если хотя бы одно из условий не выполнено, то он должен возвращать false. И другие в этом же роде. Я просто не могу правильно сформировать эти операции.

```
bool Polinom::operator == (const Polinom &t)
{
    if (deg = t.deg)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < deg; i++)
            {
                if (koef[i] = t.koef[i]);
                return true
            }
    }
    else return false;
}

bool Polinom::operator < (const Polinom &t)
{
    if((deg < t.deg) || (koef[deg] < t.koef[deg]))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Логика неправильная, но все равно: сравнение на равенство в языке С++ делается оператором `==`. `==`, а не `=`.

Comment: Какой тип имеет `koef`? Если это стандартный контейнер, можно было бы просто сделать `return koef == t.koef;`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Операция сравнения имеет представление `==`. Вы используете присваивание `=`. Это *большая* ошибка. При сравнении коэффициентов вы поставили после `if(..)` знак точку с запятой `;`.  Это означает пустой оператор (в смысле ничего не делать). Это *вторая* ошибка.  Внутри цикла нужно при *разных* коэффициентах прекратить цикл и вернуть отрицание. Примерно так:

```
bool Polinom::operator == (const Polinom &t)
{
    if (deg == t.deg)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < deg; i++)
            {
                if (koef[i] != t.koef[i])
                    return false;

            }
        return true ;
    }
    else return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
bool Polinom::operator == (const Polinom &t)
{
    //если количество членов разное, сразу возвращаем ложь
    if (deg != t.deg)
        return false;    
    for (int i = 0; i < deg; i++)
    {
        //если есть хоть одно несовпадение то неравенство
        if (koef[i] != t.koef[i]);
        return false;
    }  
    // в друих случаях  
    return true;
}
```

В ваших же условиях во первых не сравнение, а присваивание, а во вторых вы пытаетесь возвращать истину при первом же равенстве одного из членов. И потом, зачем продолжать сравнивать, если количество членов разное?